# How to subset rows of a large data.table based on a specific sum column value?

Tags: r, data.table

How to subset rows of a large data.table based on a specific sum column value?

```r
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(frequency = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1), names = c("ten", "nine", "eight", "seven", "six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "one"))

# Example: subset data.table to at least 90% of the frequency sum.

# Desired answer:

   frequency names
1:        10   ten
2:         9  nine
3:         8 eight
4:         7 seven
5:         6   six
6:         5  five
7:         4  four
8:         3 three
```

Comment: *"subset data.table to at least 90% of the frequency sum."* Do you mean the *first* instance where the sum of `frequency` is greater than 90% of the total sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
x[1:which.max(cumsum(frequency) > 0.9 * sum(frequency))]
   frequency names
1:        10   ten
2:         9  nine
3:         8 eight
4:         7 seven
5:         6   six
6:         5  five
7:         4  four
8:         3 three
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your data frame, there are two options:

1) The easy form:

```
        require(data.table)
    x <- data.table(frequency = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1), names = c("ten", "nine", "eight", "seven", "six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "one"))
    x$cumfreq <- cumsum(x$frequency)/sum(x$frequency)
    print(x)
    x <- subset(x, cumfreq <= .9)
    print(x)
    x$cumfreq # don't forget delete column for performance
    gc()
```

And 2) the elegant:

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(frequency = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1), names = c("ten", "nine", "eight", "seven", "six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "one"))
top <- quantile(x$frequency, probs = .1)
x <- subset(x, frequency> top  )
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for attention! But both solutions didn't provide the desired extraction, they didn't select row 8, which is needed to include.

Comment: thanks @DaniloCorrea, in fact Maurits Evers ' is much better